# pandas DataFrame diagonal

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

What is an efficient way to get the diagonal of a square `DataFrame`.  I would expect the result to be a `Series` with a `MultiIndex` with two levels, the first being the index of the `DataFrame` the second level being the columns of the `DataFrame`.

## Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 3) * 5,
                  columns = list('abc'),
                  index = list('ABC'),
                  dtype=np.int64
                 )
```

I want to see this:

```
print df.stack().loc[[('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c')]]

A  a    2
B  b    2
C  c    3
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you don't mind using numpy you could use `numpy.diag`

```
pd.Series(np.diag(df), index=[df.index, df.columns])

A  a    2
B  b    2
C  c    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 11):

You could do something like this:

```
In [16]:
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(df.index,df.columns)))
pd.DataFrame(data=np.diag(df), index=midx)

Out[16]:
     0
A a  2
B b  2
C c  3
```

[`np.diag`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) will give you the diagonal values as a np array, you can then construct the multiindex by zipping the index and columns and pass this as the desired index in the `DataFrame` ctor.

Actually the complex multiindex generation doesn't need to be so complicated:

```
In [18]:
pd.DataFrame(np.diag(df), index=[df.index, df.columns])

Out[18]:
     0
A a  2
B b  2
C c  3
```

But [johnchase's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310264/pandas-dataframe-diagonal/37310433#37310433) is neater

Comment: You beat me to it `numpy.diag` is a good solution. Is it necessary to pass a mutliindex though? wouldn't this work? `pd.Series(np.diag(df), index=[df.index, df.columns])`

Comment: @johnchase actually that's a better solution, I just decided to literally do what the OP asked for

Comment: @johnchase please submit an answer with that.  just ran it and works

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `iat` in a list comprehension to get the diagonal.

```
>>> pd.Series([df.iat[n, n] for n in range(len(df))], index=[df.index, df.columns]) 
A  a    2
B  b    2
C  c    3
dtype: int64
```