# Getting non-diagonal elements in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Following [pandas DataFrame diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310264/pandas-dataframe-diagonal), I can get diagonal elements using `np.diag`. How can I get the non-diagonal elements in a dataframe (assuming that dataframe is size n x n)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll use @Matt's same dataframe `xf`

```
xf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 5))
```

However, I'll point out that if the diagonal happens to be equal to zero, Using `np.diag(np.diag(xf)) != 0` will break down.

The way to guarantee that you are masking the diagonal is to evaluate if the row indices are **not equal** to the column indices.

**Option 1**
*`numpy.indices`*

Conveniently, `numpy` provides those as well via the `np.indices` function.

Observe what they look like

```
rows, cols = np.indices((5, 5))

print(rows)

[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]]

print(cols)

[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 1 2 3 4]]
```

And where they are equal... The diagonal.

```
print((cols == rows).astype(int))

[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

So with these, we can mask where they are equal with

```
xf.mask(np.equal(*np.indices(xf.shape)))

          0         1         2         3         4
0       NaN  0.605436  0.573386  0.978588  0.160986
1  0.295911       NaN  0.509203  0.692233  0.717464
2  0.275767  0.966976       NaN  0.883339  0.143704
3  0.628941  0.668836  0.468928       NaN  0.309901
4  0.286933  0.523243  0.693754  0.253426       NaN
```

---

We can make is a bit faster with

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(np.equal(*np.indices(xf.shape)), np.nan, xf.values),
    xf.index, xf.columns
)
```

**Option 2**
*`numpy.arange` with slice assignment*

```
v = xf.values.copy()
i = j = np.arange(np.min(v.shape))
v[i, j] = np.nan
pd.DataFrame(v, xf.index, xf.columns)

          0         1         2         3         4
0       NaN  0.605436  0.573386  0.978588  0.160986
1  0.295911       NaN  0.509203  0.692233  0.717464
2  0.275767  0.966976       NaN  0.883339  0.143704
3  0.628941  0.668836  0.468928       NaN  0.309901
4  0.286933  0.523243  0.693754  0.253426       NaN
```

---

```
%%timeit 
v = xf.values.copy()
i = j = np.arange(np.min(v.shape))
v[i, j] = np.nan
pd.DataFrame(v, xf.index, xf.columns)


%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.eye(np.min(xf.shape)), np.nan, xf.values), xf.index, xf.columns)
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.equal(*np.indices(xf.shape)), np.nan, xf.values), xf.index, xf.columns)
%timeit xf.mask(np.equal(*np.indices(xf.shape)))
%timeit xf.mask(np.diag(np.diag(xf.values)) != 0)
%timeit xf.mask(np.eye(np.min(xf.shape), dtype=bool)

10000 loops, best of 3: 74.5 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.7 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 77 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 519 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 517 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 528 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 12):

Use a mask generated with `np.eye` like:

```
xf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5))
xf.mask(np.eye(5, dtype = bool))
```

Comment: I'd say this is rather clever....  I've also added timings for this answer an some variations on it.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED answer to equal to SomeGuy response as the initial answer was wrong when diagonal elements were equal to `0`.

```
xf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5))
xf.mask(np.eye(5, dtype = bool))
```

#### INCORRECT INITIAL ANSWER WHEN DIAGONAL ELEMENTS ARE EQUAL TO 0

First construct mask of `True` and `False` values and then apply on your square matrix / dataframe.

```
xf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5))
diag = np.diag(np.diag(xf))
xf.mask(diag != 0)
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect if a diagonal element is equal to zero!

Comment: And now we know how bugs happen :)

Comment: Yes absolutely right @piRSquared thanks for pointing out. I have corrected the initial answer I posted to equal to the Some Guy response so that people won't use the incorrect answer going forward.