# how to use results of a column as column references? python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How would you use the results of a variable in a pandas data set to call different columns in iteratively that have the same name as the results. If one column had results that were letters and other columns were titled with those letters, how could you use the results from the letters column as column names?

Take this example data set

```
letter a b c d
a      1 3 4 2  
d      4 3 2 1 
c      2 1 4 3
d      3 4 2 1
```

desired results

```
letter a b c d  correct answer
a      1 3 4 2  1  
d      4 3 2 1  1 
c      2 1 4 3  4
d      3 4 2 1  1
```

How do you create the correct answer variable seen in the desired results

Comment: A few assumptions to clear up first: Are we assuming that there will only ever be a single match, not multiple matches? What happens in the case where there is no match?

Comment: Assuming there will only be one match. Ideally an N/A is returned if there is no match.

Comment: I think you're missing what I'm getting at; I'll try to explain better. My hope is that for each row the 'correct answer' variable will return the column of the letter in the variable 'letter'. The fact that d occurs a second time in letter is unimportant, and b not being present is unimportant as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have set `letter` as your index, I suppose you could do the following:

```
df['correct_answer'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.name], axis=1)
```

Yields:

```
        a  b  c  d  correct_answer
letter                            
a       1  3  4  2               1
d       4  3  2  1               1
c       2  1  4  3               4
d       3  4  2  1               1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might help: [pandas DataFrame diagonal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310264/pandas-dataframe-diagonal)

This is basically searching for an identity diagonal i.e. when rowname == colname. Should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I'm sure it's not guaranteed that the matches always fall on the diagonal...

Comment: Well I was hoping to apply this if it were not a diagonal pattern. I'll edit the data so that doesn't work.

Comment: you could technically perform an intersection of the rownames and colnames and make the dataframe symmetric then make the diagonal approach work

Comment: that would also reduce the search space